# Make visual studio code autocomplete property html

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm working on an Angular project in Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to make visual studio code autcomplete the properties of my model?

This is the employee model that I want the autocompletion from [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbWVj.png)

But when I'm typing I don't see the correct completions [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPd77.png)

Is there anyone who know how to enable this, is there a extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

On your typescript class You should define the type of employees array:

```
employees : Array<Employee>
```